# Labeling lines that are not within polygons using field calculator

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, labeling, within

I have two features. One line feature and another polygon feature. I want the line feature label not to appear when it is within a polygon similar to the one in the figure. That is, I want the label to only appear when the line is outside the polygon. Is it possible to do this in QGIS 3?

I tried the field calculator with the `within` function but it didn't work very well.

[image: example]

Below is the code I tried to do in the QGIS field calculator:

```sql
CASE
   WHEN within('Lines_4e1a1089_ba02_495e_8c79_d32b79cf3b54','polygon_406a7fae_06b4_45a1_a20e_d64b8682e501') THEN " "
   ELSE "Label"
END
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! I guess you mean the "Expression Dialog" that opens when you click the "ε" button right to the "Label with" combo box, not the field calculator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or in a very simple way, you can use the polygon to block the labels of the polyline.

Label polyline normally:

[image]

After using the polygon as a blocking feature, the label will be shifted automatically outside the polygon:

[image]

Comment: Oh, that is simple! I knew that there was something like this :D. However my solution could help in specific cases (repeating lables).

Comment: @OtoKaláb I like your solution. It is really great and will help in complicated cases. :)

Comment: That's a very nifty trick!

Answer (score 12):

You trying to call `within` on a string representing a layer, not its geometry. But it won't work that way anyway. This way it would label/not label whole feature, not segments. With `within` it would label feature with `" "` in case that whole line is in polygon. In case of `intersects` it will label feature that somehow interact with any polygon.

Maybe there is option how to solve this with expression of `Label with`, but I thing this is primary for formatting label text for feature, not for label placement. I didn't figure out how to split the line geometry in this expression for the desired result.

In QGIS 3.8, there is `Geometry generator` in *Placement* tab in labels properties. With this you can generate new source geometry only for labels, in your case lines that are not intersecting polygons. Labels are than rendered only over this geometry (i.e. rendering labels over polygon i suppressed):

[image: example1]

```py
if(
    intersects(
        $geometry,
        aggregate('poly','collect',$geometry,intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
    ),
    difference(
        $geometry,
        aggregate('poly','collect',buffer($geometry,0.1),intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
    ),
    $geometry
)
```

Notice the `buffer` function, this gives space around polygon to suppress label rendering. This avoids long labels overlap polygons.

Than in *Rendering tab* check the `Label every part of multi-part features`. This keeps rendering labels on all part of a line (lines that overlap the polygon and continues).

[image: example2]

[image: example3]

Comment: Awesome solution!

Answer (score 4):

Your approach does not work because

- spatial joins over layers (not tests for the relations of single geometries) cannot be performed in expression dialog
- `within` is only true when a whole geometry falls entirely into another geometry, wich is not the fact in your case
- double quotes are for attribute names, for strings use single quotes

All in all, I doubt that this can be achieved using expressions in symbology or labelling, I recommend using the **Difference** tool to compute the sections of your linestring layer that lie *outside the polygon* (Processing Toolbox > Vector Overlay > Difference):

[image]

Labelling for the original linestring layer:

[image]

Labelling for the Difference Layer:

[image]

If you want to display your original linestring layer (without labels) and use the labels from the Difference layer I suggest setting up a "No Symbol" style for the Difference layer, label it and display both of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a **data defined override** for label rendering, but it requires splitting your line layer.

1. From the processing toolbox, run the **Clip** tool to clip the line layer with the polygon layer.
2. Run the **Difference** tool to extract the parts of the line feature which fall outside the polygon.
3. Run the **Merge vector layers** tool on the clipped and difference results.
4. Add a new integer field to the merged layer and call it e.g. 'Label'.
5. Select the feature inside the polygon. Open the attribute table and, with the layer in edit mode, give it a value of 0 in the 'Label' field. Give the feature/ features outside the polygon values of 1.
6. In layer properties, label the line layer with the desired field, in the rendering tab check 'Label every part of multi-part features', then click 'data defined' for show label, and select the 'Label' field.

Label settings:

[image]

Result:

[image]